# Copy symbolic link to same file name

Tags: linux, unix

I think the reason I can't find how to do this is just because I don't know the jargon.

At my job I often need to get rid of symbolic links (to our design management database). This is because people Unix copy the directories over and need to harden the files (not sure if that is best term). OK, example:

```
$ ls -l
file1 -> /something/asdf/1235
file2 -> /something/fdsa/5431
```

Then I have to:

```
rm file1
cp /something/asdf/1235 file1
rm file2
cp /something/fdsa/5431 file2
```

It can be tedious and seems like something fundamental.

Is there a on liner so I can do this on a hundreds of files at once? Also, can someone educate me on the jargon I'd need to ask this question without an example, like "I need to turn a symbolic link into a **__**". Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
cp --remove-destination "$(readlink file1)" file1
```

The `readlink` command gives you the name of the file that the symlink is pointing to. The `cp` command then performs the copy, but removes the symlink first.

Comment: Awesome, wrote a bash script around it 
for ARG in $*
do
    cp --remove-destination "$(readlink $ARG)" $ARG
    chmod +w $ARG
done